# How to show the number of user stories/test cases by total, pending, complete, in progress, accepted?

Tags: javascript, rally, testcase

So I saw this app for rally on Github:
https://github.com/RallyApps/DefectSummaryMatrix

And I am trying to make the same thing, except for test cases and user stories, instead of defects. How would I go about doing this? I am pretty new into the rally SDK and kind of lost to be honest, so anything you guys can say would help.

I've been looking at the App.html for this, and I think this part is the part I need to pay attention to cause this is where it gets the information about the defects:

```
var defectQuery = function() {
        var selected = releaseDropdown.getSelectedName();
        var releaseQuery = '(Release.Name = "' + selected + '")';
        var queryObject = [];
        queryObject[0] = { key: 'defectStates', type: 'Defect', attribute: 'State' };
        queryObject[1] = { key: 'defectPriorities', type: 'Defect', attribute: 'Priority' };
        queryObject[2] = {
            key: 'defects',
            type: 'Defect',
            query: releaseQuery,
            fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,State,Priority,ScheduleState,ObjectID,Description,owner,DisplayName,LoginName'
        };
        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
    };
```

How do I modify this to get information about user stories? I think the `type` field would be called `userStory` or something like that, but then what would the key and attributes be? I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

See Rally object model in [Web Services API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) documentation. 
User stories are called "HierarchicalRequirement" in the WS API. Click on HierarchicalRequirement object in the object model to go over the attributes.

I suggest that you do not use the DefectSummaryMatrix as a starting point. It is a legacy app that is using legacy AppSDK1. Use [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/) instead. There is an example of multi-type object grid [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/multi-type-grid).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I looked at the hierarchical requirement object, but it seems that this is for a single user story. What I need to do is calculate the # of user stories in a release. I looked at the release object, but it doesnt seem to have any attribute which has the # of user stories in a release. Do you have an idea of how I would go about doing this?

Comment: HierarchicalRequirement  object has Release attribute. You have to query on stories that are scheduled for a Release, e.g. (Release.Name = "release 1") and write your code so that it sums up data you are interested in as you iterate over the query results. Also see https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/timebox_filtering